# Identity for the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

Euler created the following expression for the Euler-Mascheroni constant: $$\gamma=\sum^\infty_{k=1} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)\right)$$ This converges more rapidly than the original definition: $$\gamma=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} H(x)-\ln(x)$$ Where $H(x)$ is the $x$th harmonic number. Anyway, I derived a generalization of Euler's sum: $$\gamma=\sum^\infty_{k=1} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{k} \right)}{z}\right)-\frac{\ln (z!)}{z}$$ Where $z$ is literally any number. I derived this formula using the Weierstrass definition of the Gamma function and then simplifying. Is this novel?

Thanks for taking your time to read this whole post!

Comment: The sum you describe as better is just $H(n)-\log(n+1)$ in partial sum.

Comment: (1) Please do not create new tags without first gauging community interest in such a tag.  There is a dedicated meta thread for [tag management](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/tag-management-2022).  (2) Please to not make inconsequential edits to a post just to "bump" it to the front page.  If you believe that your post is not getting enough attention, please consider starting a bounty.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How did you get that? I am interested, since (1) The identity has an infinite sum and (2) it is actually more than one identity because of the $z$

Comment: @KamalSaleh I was just talking about the first sum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that was Euler's identity by the way.